# Where to put PHP code in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am really new to Laravel as well as PHP.

I have some PHP code that I want to put it in Laravel. 
But when I check the .blade files there are no PHP codes contained in them.

So, my question is: When can I put my PHP code in a Laravel application.
The PHP code relates to single.blade.

Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: Have you read official tutorial?

Comment: In fact, you may put your PHP code anywhere composer's autoloader can find them

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How do I reference it so that it executes when single.blade is called? Please let me know.

Comment: Did you read the documentation? http://laravel.com/docs/templates

Comment: Seriously, if you are new to PHP then learn PHP basics **before** trying any framework. Your future "you" will be grateful.

Comment: the template needs to be named `single.blade.php`.  It has to end in `.php` to be compiled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blade is the Laravel template, you should not put your code inside the blade file, it is not a good practice (not recommended), just things you are going to show on the final page.

You should put your code inside the controller.

So if you want to pass things to Blade you should do like:

```
View::make('single', array('var1' => $var1, 'var2' => $var2));
```

Everything between {{ }} is tranformed to an echo by Blade, so you can use any PHP code like this {{ date('d/m/y') }} on your Blade files.

So with this example above you should do {{ $var1 }} on your Blade file.

But with Blade you have flow control:

If-else:

```
@if ($var1 == $var2)
    <p> equal </p>
@else
    <p> not equal </p>
@endif
```

For-each:

```
@foreach($vars as $var)
    <p>{{ $var }}</p>
@endforeach
```

For:

```
@for($i=0 ; $i<999 ; $i++)
  <p>Number: {{ $i }}</p>
@endfor
```

While:

```
@while(isTrue($var))
  <p>Loop forever</p>
@endwhile
```

Unless:

```
@unless(isRunning())
  <p>keep</p>
@endunless
```

With this you can control what is printed on screen and you can use Laravel code like this (this code is adding an HTML class if the current route is equal to 'getFoo' to the element LI):

```
<li @if(URL::current() == URL::route('getFoo'))class="active"@endif>
```

This is a good start on how to use Blade. http://laravel.com/docs/templates